# Why arent the threads running concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am running a very simple multi thread program

**Main program**

```
package javathread;


public class JavaThread {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        JThread t1 = new JThread(10,1);
        JThread t2 = new JThread(10,2);

        t1.run();
        t2.run();

    }
}
```

**JThread.java**

```
package javathread;

import java.util.Random;

public class JThread implements Runnable
{
    JThread(int limit , int threadno)
    {
        t = new Thread();
        this.limit = limit;
        this.threadno = threadno;

    }

    public void run()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();

        for (int i=0;i<this.limit;i++)
        {
            int num = generator.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Thread " + threadno + " : The num is " + num   );
            try
            {
            Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {

            }
        }

    }




    Thread t;
    private int limit;
    int threadno;
}
```

I expect both threads to run concurrently/parrallel , something similar to this picture

[image]

Instead I am getting this where thread 1 runs first then thread 2 runs

[image]

**Can someone explain to me why this is happening ??**

**How do i get the threads to run concurrently ??**

Comment: dude, read about thread basics first. Thread life cycle starts from the call to start method on the Thread object and not on run. run is called internally by thread to execute your 'run' based task concurrently.

Comment: Making `run` public together with making `Thread` not final must be some of the worst design decisions in the Java API, the amount confusion that would have avoided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you called `t1.run()` and `t2.run()` instead of `t1.start()` and `t2.start()`.

If you call `run`, it's just a normal method call. It doesn't return until it's finished, just like any method. It does not run anything concurrently. There is absolutely nothing special about `run`.

`start` is the "magic" method that you call to start another thread and call `run` in the new thread. (Calling `start` is also a normal method call, by the way. It's the code inside `start` that does the magic)

Comment: his problem is much more basic: JThread implements Runnable and it is not an actual thread (I think he tried to use an actual thread by creating it in the Ctor of the JThread).

Comment: I thought so as well. it took me a while to notice too :P

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the `Life Cycle of a Thread`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you don't run anything on the Thread, you just run the Runnable (your JThread is NOT a thread, it is just a unnable).
to run on a thread, you need to do something like this:

```
new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```

creating the thread in the Runnable does nothing (like you did in JThread constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Because you should `start()` the Thread, **not** `run()` it.